# How to get particular images from an Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm new to iOS development, I have an array of images where some of the images can be nil in some cases, For a button click even I need to get the images which are not nil from that particular array, Please help me how to sort out this issue

This is the array which I have where some images are nil:

```
self.fruitImages = @[imageview1.image, imageview2.image, imageview3.image, imageview4.image, imageview5.image];
```

I need to remove all the images which are nil in this array and `NSLog` the rest of the images in this array.

Comment: @NiravD I was going to suggest that as well, but he's asking about Objective-C

Comment: where is the __*some images* are nil__? Does these images are from `UIImageView` or stored images with name from `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C arrays (or rather, `NSArrays`) can't contain nil. The only thing you can put in an `NSArray` is `NSNull`, and object that *represents* nil. If, in your code above, one of the variables contains nil, the array will be truncated at that point.

### EDIT:

Actually the code the OP posted will crash if any of the values passed in are nil.

Comment: True for compiler check. That one is about inserting nil objects during a runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
self.fruitImages = @[imageview1.image, imageview2.image, imageview3.image, imageview4.image, imageview5.image];
```

this code will occurs crash if one of .image == nil

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray
>   initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil

Try to use NSMutableArray and insert new item if it's not nil

**Example:**

```
NSArray *imageViews = @[imageV1, imageV2, imageV3];

NSMutableArray *result  = [NSMutableArray new];
for (UIImageView *imgV in imageViews) {
    if (imgV.image) {
        [result addObject:imgV.image];
    }
}

self.fruitImages = [result copy];
```

Comment: True but that syntax does not fail : self.fruitImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:imageview1.image, imageview2.image, imageview3.image, imageview4.image, imageview5, nil];

Comment: @Adobels, that code won't crash, but if any of the images passed in are nil, the array will be truncated at that point and any valid images that follow will not be included. So `self.fruitImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:imageview1.image, imageview2.image, <nil>, imageview4.image, imageview5.image, nil];` (where `<nil>` represents an expression that evaluates to nil, will cause the array to not contain `imageview4.image` or `imageview5.image`. Thus it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
NSArray *ivs = @[imageview1, imageview2, imageview3, imageview4, imageview5];
NSMutableArray *mivs = [[ivs valueForKey:@"image"] mutableCopy];
[mivs removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
self.fruitImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mivs];
```

Good to know :

```
UIImageView * im1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
UIImageView * im2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"]];
UIImageView * im3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];

NSArray *arrayA = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:im1.image, im2.image, im3.image, nil];
NSArray *arrayB = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:im2.image, im1.image, im3.image, nil];
NSArray *arrayC = @[im2.image, im1.image, im3.image];
NSArray *arrayD = @[im1.image, im2.image, im3.image];
```

ArrayA has 0 elements

ArrayB has 1 element

ArrayC Crash

ArrayD Crash

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:imageview1.image, imageview2.image, imageview3.image, imageview4.image, imageview5.image, nil];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (imgArray.count != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= imgArray.count - 1; i++) {
            UIImage *img = [imgArray objectAtIndex:i];
            if (img == nil) {
                [tempArray addObject:[imgArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
    }
    [imgArray removeObjectsInArray:tempArray];
```

Comment: It does not work correctly. Try     UIImageView * im1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    UIImageView * im2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"]];
    UIImageView * im3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];